# Search and Add characters to Google sheet value array with GAS?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a problem with finding conditional values ​​and replacing them in a Google sheet data array.

I have an array of data in column A.

1. I want to find the values ​​without the "." is an integer
2. And add a . and any natural number.
3. Write new data in column B.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  var range = sheet.getRange('a:a') 
  }
```

I am new with GAS, and this topic will help me so much,

Thank you for give me a help.

Comment: Could you provide an example of an input and expected output ?

Comment: Can you explain what 'values ​​without the "." is an integer' is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myFunction() {
  const n = 123;
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const row = sheet.getLastRow();
  const range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, row, 1); 
  const values = range.getValues();
  const results = values.map(e => {
    if (Number.isInteger(e[0])) {
      return [`${e[0]}.${n}`];
    }
    else {
      return [''];
    }
  });
  sheet.getRange(1, 2, row, 1).setValues(results);
}
```